# MenuStrip Interface

Tags: vb.net

How can i add MenuStrip Look Like Below picture ?

[image]

My MenuStrip is below picture :

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Are you explicitly overriding any themes?

Comment: @Austin Salonen all of my windows application has this interface but for my application not, it means all of them change default theme ?

Comment: ... or perhaps you do?  I only ask because it's exactly what I was doing back in a Vista environment.

Comment: @Austin Salonen : I Only add a MenuStrip To My Mdi WindowsForm .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click the toolbox and select "Choose Items".  Tick the MainMenu component.  There might be more than one, pick the one whose Directory column says Global Assembly Cache.

That's the .NET 1.x version of the menu component.  It uses the native Windows menu support api, unlike MenuStrip which is a complete rewrite to add features to menus that Windows doesn't support.  Unfortunately, they didn't have a time machine to guess what the future version of it was going to look like.  Which otherwise explains why MainMenu makes your program look very similar to other Windows 7 applets like Notepad.