# How can I use old menu style in C# Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, qt, winforms-interop

I'm working on a C# Winforms app and I want to use the old menu style as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Old Menu style]

This is the same menu style used in Qt Apps.

Unfortunately, in C# Winforms, the menu looks like this :

[image: New Menu style]

Is there any solution to implement the old menu style in C# Winforms ?

Comment: Use the [MainMenu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mainmenu(v=vs.110).aspx) component instead of .NET's own MenuStrip.

Comment: @VisualVincent [D'oh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27oh!), that's probably the thing (should have asked to show some source code from the beginning). And you should write it as an answer - or it can be marked as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748144/main-menu-in-c-sharp.

Comment: Duplicate is better.